# How to handle session in socket.io and express in node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets, session, socket.io, chat

I'm new to socket.io. I'm developing a website with a chat subpage. Before someone enters chat he must fill form with email, name and so on. After logging you can chat with a consultant. Unfortunatelly I can not go to any other subpage because when I enter my chat subpage again it requires logging again and starts new conversation. My question is how to handle user chat session?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Usually, you would put some sort of session ID in a cookie after the user logs in and subsequent pages will present that cookie so your server will know which user it is the next time they connect.

Comment: Ok. Do you know how to handle this using express-session? Because socket request is different than normal htp request.

Comment: All socket.io requests start with an HTTP requests and the socket.io library  saves the cookie settings at that time so they are available from a `socket` object at any time on the server via `socket.request.headers.cookie`.  Relevant [socket.io doc here](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket#request:request).